# Elements of a free module written uniquely as a linear combination of basis elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ a free $R$-module with basis $X$. Is it so that every $m \in M$ can be written *uniquely* as a linear combination of elements of $X$?

If not, in which cases is that true?

**Update:** In the book I'm learning from, a basis of $M$ is defined to be a linearly independent, spanning subset of $M$.

Comment: There are multiple ways to define "basis", which are you using?

Comment: The answer is yes by the way, we just need to know which definition you're using in order to explain *why* the answer is yes.

Comment: @user138093: the definition you use is equivalent to the definition I used below.see for example:   *6.51& 6.52* of the book **Steps in Commutative Algebra** (Second edition) $[R. Y. Sharp]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $m = ∑r_i  e_i = ∑s_i  e_i$ then $∑(r_i-s_i)  e_i=0$ so by independence we have $r_i=s_i$

Comment: Don't we also need the choice of basis elements to be unique? i.e. to show that $\sum r_ie_i=\sum s_if_i \Rightarrow r_i=s_i$ and $e_i=f_i$, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Christopher.L : Well, I suppose since all $e_i, f_i$:s are in $X$, we could just rearrange and "fill out" with $r_i, s_i =0$ when needed to get both representations on the form $\sum v_ie_i$.